# @bot.command() AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
client = discord.Client(command_prefix='x!')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Successfully booted the bot up!")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find("minecraft") != -1:
        await message.channel.send('@Kerina#4436 ajde majnkraft jebemlite')


@client.command()
async def nwordpass(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Proof of you having the nword pass: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1HBSAiHdRdM1UVJJZlOUnMkihkiMOPPYSMTjI5WzHuvDVIBztueZR83rkUiHwIJvrfU')


client.run("NzA2MzE0MTc3NjQzNDEzNTY1.Xq4cYw.A-6MruzAgtLC1maW4VVIB2HlFM4")
```

Why doesn't it work?
I tried almost every common fix but didn't get any positive results

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Bot` class from `discord.ext.commands`

```
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='x!')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Successfully booted the bot up!")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find("minecraft") != -1:
        await message.channel.send('@Kerina#4436 ajde majnkraft jebemlite')
    await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command()
async def nwordpass(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Proof of you having the nword pass: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1HBSAiHdRdM1UVJJZlOUnMkihkiMOPPYSMTjI5WzHuvDVIBztueZR83rkUiHwIJvrfU')
```

I also added the `await client.process_commands(message)` line so that your commands are processed.

Answer (score -1):

The sample code at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/extensions.html#id1 indicates that the correct code would look like this:

```py
@commands.command()
async def nwordpass(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Proof of you having the nword pass: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1HBSAiHdRdM1UVJJZlOUnMkihkiMOPPYSMTjI5WzHuvDVIBztueZR83rkUiHwIJvrfU')
```

That is, the `command()` decorator is defined on the `commands` module, not on the `Client` instance objects.

Comment: I think its because instead of commands i defined it as a client, and on the docs it says commands cause they defined "commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')"  to it